# Angular js date filter "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" to "MMM d, yyyy h mm"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, filter

I have a date like this

```
2019-02-15 16:01:18
```

and i am trying to show this in following format:

```
 Feb 2, 2019 4:01 PM
```

How can i achive this with date filter:
here is what i tried:

```
{{ myDate | date:'MMM  d, yyyy hh:mm' }}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe - use 'medium'? Note the equivalent format also differs. If there are more details supplied with the question - eg. "What doesn't work / and how does it 'not work'?" - then the question will be better received.

Comment: @user2864740 i have tried medium but not working `{{ myDate  | date:'medium' }}`.! i am still gettting this o/p:
`2019-02-15 16:01:18`

Comment: You sure `myDate` is `Date` not `String`

Comment: it's a `string only` that is the reason I am using `date pipe` to treat as `date time`.

Comment: The date pipe is used to present a `Date` as a formatted `String` - not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it appears you are starting with a `String`, not a `Date`.

```
var dateString = "2019-02-15 16:01:18";
$scope.myDate = new Date(dateString);
```

Then you can use the date filter as you have tried:

```
{{ myDate | date:'MMM  d, yyyy hh:mm' }}
```